# Haskell: Recursing in a `do` block

Tags: haskell

I am trying to achieve loop-like functionality in a Haskell program, via recursion with `main`. The following code *should* print a `*` to STDOUT every 2 seconds, indefinitely:

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)   --(This function stalls the IO for given number of microseconds 
main = do 
        threadDelay 2000000
        Prelude.putChar '*'
        main
```

It compiles fine, but accumulates the output `*`s and only displays them when the program is aborted, rather than printing another `*` every 2 seconds (why?). Is this 'loop' like programming with `main` an accepted programming style, or is there a better way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: You need to call `hFlush stdout` after the `putChar` call. You can import them from `System.IO`. And yes, it's fine to implement a loop in that way. Another way is to use `forever` from `Control.Monad`.